# Why is "enter" not working for my form?

Tags: javascript, passwords

Here is the code, I can't figure out why enter/return isn't working!  Is it because it's `inline`?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap"><form name="login" style="margin: 0px">
<label for="fname">CLICK TO ENTER PASSWORD</label>
<input TYPE="text" NAME="pass" size="17" onKeyDown="e.keyCode == 13;"  id="fname"  class="cool"><br><input type="button" value="LOGIN"  class="asbestos-flat-button" onClick="TheLogin(this.form)">
</form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--- PASSWORD PROTECTION SCRIPT
function TheLogin() {
var password = 'password';

if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
  top.location.href="home.html";
}
else {
  location.href="index.html";
  }
}
// End hiding --->
</script>
```

### I'm learning JS so any help would be so awesome!

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your help. Still not working when integrated. The page doesn't load the `home.html` when I hit enter/return. Instead I get no refresh, and the address bar has the `url` http://example.com/?pass=password.

If I click the button it does load the **home.html**!

thanks!

Comment: try to add submit button and test

Comment: Why are you using some input tags with uppercase characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here I wrote a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aforni/9dwjxfag/2/) with the working example.

In the HTML code:

- Remove `onKeyDown="e.keyCode == 13;"` from the `<input>` text element.
- Remove `onClick="TheLogin(this.form)"` from the `<input>` button element.
- Change the type of input button from 'button' to 'submit'. In this way, when you press "enter" in the input text form the form is submitted.
- Intercept the "submit" event in the form, adding `onSubmit="theLogin(this.form)"` on `<form>` element.

**Note:** I have renamed the function name from "TheLogin" to "theLogin" because in JavaScript the functions begins with lowercase letters if they are not constructors.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <form name="login" style="margin: 0px" onSubmit="theLogin(this.form)">
        <label for="fname">CLICK TO ENTER PASSWORD</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="pass" size="17" id="fname" class="cool">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" class="asbestos-flat-button">
    </form>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
theLogin = function() {
    var password = 'password';

    if (this.document.login.pass.value === password) {
        top.location.href = "home.html";
    } else {
        location.href = "index.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: it's actually still not working when i integrate it into my site :(

Comment: it comes back with no refresh, and my address bar now says  "http:/mydomain.com/?pass=password

Comment: Well, this is another problem. Your question was about why pressing enter from the input field does not trigger the "theLogin" function. My answer solve this problem.
The problem you are describing me know is different. Let me think about it...

Comment: Thank you @Andrea!  I thought it was the same problem because if i actually click the button, it works fine!  I am copy and pasting too much, i must learn :p  THANK YOU THANK YOU xxxxx

Comment: Your welcome  @pixelgirrrl ! If you think that my answer was the most accurate and helped you, please "accept" my answer :)

Comment: I will!  But do you have an idea how i can fix the issue?  it is still not solved..

Comment: Usually, to implement a login form, you display a form with a text area for the username and one for the password. When the submit button is clicked, a request to a backend server is done, passing the username and password inserted. The backend validate the credential and issue a redirect to the client to the correct page. So the logic inside the `theLogin` function should be moved server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `<input type="submit">`, without it you can't use the Enter key to submit the form.